# Как добавить информацию в компонент JList?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Я добавил диалоговое окно в среде IDEA и установил там компонент JList. Теперь при нажатии кнопки Ok пытаюсь добавить в JList некую инфомацию,

```
String[] str = {"a", "b"};
   list1 = new JList(str);
```

но она туда не попадает. Что я не так делаю?

Полный код:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;

public class Dialog extends JDialog {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JButton buttonOK;
    private JButton buttonCancel;
    private JList list1;

    public Dialog() {
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        setModal(true);
        getRootPane().setDefaultButton(buttonOK);

        buttonOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                onOK();
            }
        });

        buttonCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                onCancel();
            }
        });

// call onCancel() when cross is clicked
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                onCancel();
            }
        });

// call onCancel() on ESCAPE
        contentPane.registerKeyboardAction(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                onCancel();
            }
        }, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
    }

    private void onOK() {

        //Вот мой код                                                                                  
        String[] str = {"a", "b"};
        list1 = new JList(str);

    }

    private void onCancel() {
// add your code here if necessary
        dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Меняйте модель JList так:

```
private void onOk(){
DefaultListModel model = new DefaulListModel();
model.addElement("a");
model.addElement("b");
list1.setModel(model);
}
```

Comment: Переменную list1 создавал не я - весь код мне сгенерировал IDE. Я не понял куда именно вставить ваш код создания модели и списка? Ведь надо не только создать, а еще и привязать list1 с формой.

Comment: замените ваш метод onOk() на этот